# Ubuntu 18.04 update problem "g_strchug: assertion 'string != NULL' failed"

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 18.04

When I update Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, there is a flood of errors:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
(appstreamcli:30076): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:36:32.027: g_strchug: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(appstreamcli:30076): GLib-CRITICAL **: 20:36:32.027: g_strchomp: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
corrupted double-linked list
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Also, when I check my Ubuntu version, it shows `18.04` in terminal, but in startup it shows `16.04`. How to resolve this?

Comment: Similar `Glib-CRITICAL` errors running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d -m desktop` upgrading 16.04 to 18.04 but installation proceeds. I'll update later if it crashes.

Comment: Have you tried clean install yet?

Comment: no i didnot. Seems like massive crash on system

Comment: I have a similar problem (but without the crash), with appstreamcli 0.10.6. My situation is pretty much the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051536/appstreamcli-appstream-system-cache-was-updated-but-problems-were-found-metad), which is wrongly marked as duplicate (see comments there). If your case has the same cause, it boils down to a bug in `fwupd` which has been fixed. According to the devs, [ubuntu needs to backport this fix into 16.04](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/565#issuecomment-402541089).

Comment: I have a similar problem. Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Most applications are not working,  and, in journalctl, I see lots of: "/usr/bin/nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lig/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_stuctured_standard" (you can replace nautilus with 30 other applications)