# Error in Ubuntu 18.04 for sudo apt-get update : AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management

Whenever I try to run the command `sudo apt-get update` throws an error:

```
Hit:1 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                             
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                        
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                   
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Hit:6 https://qgis.org/debian bionic InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I tried so many solutions suggested on this forum but nothing worked for me. When I tried   `apt install --reinstall libappstream4 appstream` I got following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 125 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 appstream amd64 0.12.0-3ubuntu1 [27.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libappstream4 amd64 0.12.0-3ubuntu1 [97.2 kB]
Fetched 125 kB in 0s (7,261 kB/s)     
(Reading database ... 426325 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../appstream_0.12.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking appstream (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) over (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libappstream4_0.12.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libappstream4:amd64 (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) over (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libappstream4:amd64 (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up appstream (0.12.0-3ubuntu1) ...
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
```

& for : `appstreamcli refresh --force` It gave :

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz, /var/lib/app-info/yaml/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
```

Further I tried `rm -rf /var/lib/app-info/yaml/*` but error still persistent. Even I tried `sudo apt-get purge libappstream3` but it gave an error `E: Unable to locate package libappstream3` I saw some solutions like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051536/appstreamcli-appstream-system-cache-was-updated-but-problems-were-found-metad) but there is nothing in `/var/cache/app-info/xmls` for my system.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Problem executing scripts APT Update::Post-Invoke-Success error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge)

Comment: @karel No...I tried that also but it gave  ```E: Unable to locate package libappstream3```